# Javascript with jQuery for slider. Strange loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a script that I'm using for a slider. In this slider I've 2 button left and right for visit the slides. I've used jQuery and a bit of Javascript for do this. I'm using a button for play/pause but after the 3rd time the slider crash and it goes really fast.

**The button**

```
<input type="button" class="pausa" value="PAUSE" />
```

**The script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var one = "label#arrow-";
    var x = 2;
    var y = 0;
    var two = ".arrows";
    function clickin() {
        if(jQuery('.pausa').data('clicked')) {
            jQuery('.pausa').click(function(){
                $(this).data('clicked', false);
                $(this).val('PAUSE');
                return setTimeout(clickin, 4000);
            });
        }
        else {
            while ((x != 7) && (y == 0)) {
                $(one + x + two).trigger('click');
                x++;
                if (x != 7)
                    return setTimeout(clickin, 4000);
            }
            if (x == 7) {
                y = 1;
                x = 5;
            }
            while ((x != 0) && (y == 1)) {
                $(one + x + two).trigger('click');
                x--;
                if (x != 7)
                    return setTimeout(clickin, 4000);
            }
            if (x == 0) {
                y = 0;
                x = 2;
                return setTimeout(clickin, 4000);;
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(clickin, 4000);
    jQuery('.pausa').click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        $(this).val('PLAY');
        return clickin();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've made a few sliders... I would imagine that the setTimeouts are getting stacked on top of eachother each time that you click, so that they end up playing on after another.

For starters, don't use nested setTimeouts like this, unless you are going to unset it before you run another one.

The easier way I've found, which I can try to write up, is to use a variable to let you know if the slider is currently moving or not, that you can toggle when you want to stop... basically the first thing clickin could do is check 'isPlaying == true' and just return if it is.

Comment: Is there a reason that each slide has a button and not just the slider as a whole?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a manual slider with a set of 6 buttons for this reason i'm incrementing the var x, to click and slide (operation that i should do manually)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wagiwusojuni/2/edit

Here's a crude example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it:

You can check the complete code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilsen/4qgryqd3/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = "label#arrow-";
var two = ".arrows";
var x = 2;        //Value of the button
var point = 0;    //Check if you are pressing for play or pause    
function clickin() {
    if(point % 2)
        $('.pausa').val('PLAY');    //Rotation Pause
    else
        $('.pausa').val('PAUSA');   //Rotation Play
    if(!(point % 2))                //If it's in Play (Pause for button)
    {
        $(one + x + two).trigger('click');
        x++;
        if(x == 7)
            x = 1;
        return setTimeout(clickin, 4000)
    }
    else return 1;                  //If it's in Pause (Play for button)
}
setTimeout(clickin, 4000);
jQuery('.pausa').click(function(){  //Waiting input click
    point++;
    return clickin()
});
});
```